# Why is searching by one varchar column not working correctly on replica?

Tags: postgresql, replication, select, postgresql-9.6

PostgreSQL: 9.6, master, replica. 
Async replication, wal archiving.

We detected that if we execute a `select` query on a `varchar` column against a replica, then the results return no rows, but if we execute against a master then the results will be correct.

```
SELECT id FROM platform WHERE name = 'test'
```

- Master: 10
- Replica: now rows

```
SELECT name FROM platform WHERE id = 10
```

- Master: test
- Replica: test

```
SELECT id FROM platform WHERE name in ('test', 'test1')
```

- Master: 10, 11
- Replica: 11

```
SELECT name FROM platform WHERE id in (10, 11)
```

- Master: test, test1
- Replica: test, test1

I didn't find any information about such issues and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Yes (both queries), returns same row count on master and replica.

Comment: Plausible explanation: your `name` column is indexed and your replica has a different sort order than your master for the same collation. See if you're concerned by recent glibc changes in this area: https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/08/27/glibc-upgrade.html

Comment: @DanielVérité Yes, the column is indexed. I see replica has a different sort order on same queries. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you say the column is indexed, try dropping and creating the index again. It might have gotten corrupted during replication.